# How to know when the app is open (and not when onCreate is called)?

Tags: android, statistics

I want to track app opens in android but the problem is that onCreate for the main activity could be called multiple times when the orientation change. is there another way to track app open ?

Answer (score 1):

Other methods than `onCreate()` could be used :

1. OnStart()
2. OnRestart()
3. OnResume()

You'll want to consult [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) of the documentation in order to decide which one fits your needs better as they all get called in different situations.

Alternatively, you could always handle the orientation change yourself, that way the `onCreate()` method wouldn't be called when the screen rotates:

Modifications to the Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Add this method in the Activity :

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to consider handling orientation changes by yourself? That way, onCreate is not called when orientation changes (which is not a very good idea if you have different layouts for potrait and landscape). You can then rely on onStart method which is called when the screen is turned off/on, or when the activity resumes.

Answer (score 0):

The activity is open when onCreate is called, and closes when onDestroy is called. Each onCreate will always be paired with an onDestroy; when the orientation changes, the activity is (by default) first destroyed, then recreated in the new orientation.

Comment: onDestroy is not usually called ny the OS when the activity ends. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29